# Why am I getting an error telling me the constructor is not naming a type?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I am using `Code::Blocks`. Here is my code

```
#include "LargeInt.h"

LargeInt::LargeInt()
{

}
```

Header

```
#ifndef LARGEINT_H
#define LARGEINT_H


class LargeInt
{
    public:
        LargeInt();
};

#endif // LARGEINT_H
```

The error that I am getting is

> 'LargeInt does not name a type' in line 3 of my class

All I did was click file > new > class and then started coding without changing any settings or anything like that.

Comment: What are you trying to do inside the constructor?

Comment: I tried this with both a console application and an empty project

Comment: In response to stfrabbit I will try to get an input from the user using my overloaded insertion operator

Comment: What are you trying to do with `LargeInt::operator+(LargeInt){}` inside your constructor?

Comment: Did you copy&paste the exact code? Are you sure you didn't write `#ifdef` instead of `#ifndef`? Did you save the `LargeInt.h` file? Did you save it in the same directory as `LargeInt.cpp`?

Comment: Turns out code blocks put them into different folders by default. I scrapped the project and redid it, this time i checked the button that said "put header file and implementation file in the same folder" -.-

Answer (score 3):

You should not define operators within your constructor. They should be separate methods in your CPP file.

Comment: Good point, I forgot that. But that doesn't change the error. In fact I just tested it an I get the error just after making the class. I didn't even add additional code this time.

Comment: Maybe update your post with the clean code to make it easier for review.

Comment: Done. Didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is supposed to perform any operations needed to get an object of type `LargeInt` into a valid state. It seems like you're trying to define the functions `operator<<` and `operator+` inside the constructor - you can't do this:

```
LargeInt::LargeInt()
{
    LargeInt::operator<<(String input){}
    LargeInt::operator+(LargeInt){}
}
```

You should define each function that has a corresponding declaration from the class definition. Your implementation file should look something like this:

```
LargeInt::LargeInt()
{
    // ...
}

LargeInt LargeInt::operator<<(String str)
{
    // ...
    return some_large_int;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is, LargeInt &large)
{
    // ...
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, LargeInt &large)
{
    // ...
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I completely messed up the code and posted it without thinking -.- However, I still get that problem even if i remove everything but the default code that was there when I created the class